# windows phone folder lock app development

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

its first time to develop windows phone 8 app. folder lock is first on the list.
I'm familiar with c,c++ but not with c#.
what should I learn from c# for folder lock ??
and also I'm getting trouble installing windows phone sdk and emulator to existing visual studio 2013. Even if I have 64 bit windows 8 pro installed on computer, error is like
**"This computer doesn't support windows phone emulator,Which requires 64bit edition of windows 8.1 pro and computer that supports hyper-V"**
my pc configuration is
processor: pentium Dual core 2.70GHz
RAM: 4GB
x64bit processor

Comment: Is Hyper-V as a windows features enabled...if not go to control panel ->windows features-> Enable Hyper-V...for this virtualization must be enabled in BIOS ..for details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx...for c# and windows app developement there are lot of guided courses on MVA and channel 9...they are pretty useful

Comment: hey I couln't see your reply yet. thanks so much first. I tried enabling Hyper V from windows features. but it didn't worked it gives same error. I dont know how to make virtualization enabled in BIOS. and link that you send doesn't go there.. I'm thinking to buy laptop for development. and one friend said laptop that having 8gb ram and qaud core processor would be suitable for that.. but do you think 4gb ram and quad core is enough for that?? I couldn't buy 8gb ram laptop so.. and I want to do these things immediately... it already took me about month since i decided to develop app

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not have Hyper-V enabled or your hardware does not support- 
Running Hyper-V.

Windows Phone 8 Emulator:

Windows 8 Pro edition or greater

Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)

Solution: Install windows Pro edition and then go in BIOS, check the Hyper-V status and work accordingly.

Follow this link for more information:

http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8-emulator%e2%80%99s-hardware-requirements